# Path integrals for arbitrary actions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, action

All presentations I know about path integrals e.g. in quantum mechanics deduce the formulas considering a Hamiltonian of the form $$H = \frac{1}{2m}p^{2}+V(x).$$ The final expression is:
$$\langle x_{f},t_{f}|x_{i},t_{i}\rangle = \int Dx(t) e^{i\frac{S[x(t)]}{\hbar}} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $S[x(t)]$ is the associate action. Analogously, in QFT, one usually takes:
$$H = \int d^{3}x\bigg{(}\frac{1}{2}\pi^{2}(x) + V[\phi]\bigg{)} $$
and we get:
$$\langle 0| 0\rangle = \int D\phi e^{iS[\phi]} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $S$ is, again, the associate action.

**Question:** It seems to me that these choices of $H$ are not the most general one can use, but they are used to ease the deduction of the formulae. Does (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) also hold for arbitrary actions? I'm a little confused about the range of validity of such formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general actions, the formula is
$$
\langle x_f , t_f | x_i , t_i \rangle = \int [ d x (t) ] [ d p ( t ) ] e^{ \frac{i}{\hbar} \int dt  \left( p(t) {\dot q}(t) - H [ q(t) , p(t) ] \right) } 
$$
If the Hamiltonian takes the form $H[q,p] = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q)$, then we can perform the integral over $p$ exactly and we reproduce equation (1) that you wrote.

Comment: Prahar very nice! How about the path integral in QFT? Does it become an integral over $\pi$ and $\phi$ as well?

Comment: QFT is "trivial" generalization over QM. $p \to \pi$, $q \to \phi$ and you integrate over $x$ as well.

Comment: There is also the small detail that one needs to use the Wyle ordered Hamiltonian for this to work out.